# why DFS is not optimal but BFs is optimal

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have this question in my mind for long but never got reasonable answer for that :

Usually in artifitial intelligent course when it comes to search it is always said that BFS is optimal but DFS is not but I can come up with many example that shows with DFS we can even get the answer faster. So can anyone explain it ? Am I missing something?

Comment: Optimal in terms of time-complexity (execution performance) or space-complexity (memory usage)? Or in the actual quality of the output, when the best possible solution is very hard to calculate (such as in the case of a greedy algorithm for example)?

Comment: @barakmanos usually, in the context of AI, optimality refers to the solution, not to the strategy. I guess this is what the OP means.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Optimal as in "produces the optimal path", not "is the fastest algorithm possible". When searching a state space for a path to a goal, DFS may produce a much longer path than BFS. Note that BFS is only optimal when actions are unweighted; if different actions have different weights, you need something like A*.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. What about this scenario: The goal is in the left most branch of tree. Which one is optimal in this situation?

Comment: @HamedMinaee: If you know the goal is in the left-most branch of the tree, you don't need a search algorithm at all. Just take the first action in the list every time. It's not a particularly common case, so it's not useful to optimize for that case.

Comment: You neeed a specific heuristic to use A*. If you can't find one, then Uniform Cost Search (a modified BFS) might help.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: Well, you can usually at least get *something* to use as a heuristic. If you've already written A* and you can't come up with a heuristic, the "Are We There Yet?" function will get you UCS with a bit of overhead.

Answer (score 4):

This is because by *optimal strategy* they mean the one whose returned solution maximizes the utility.

Regarding this, nothing *guarantees* that the first solution found by DFS s optimal. Also BFS is not optimal in a general sense, so your statement as-is is wrong.

The main point here is about being *guaranteed* that a certain search strategy will *always* return the optimal result. Any strategy might be the best in a given case, but often (especially in AI), you don't know in what specific case you are, at most you have some hypothesis on that case.

However, **DFS is optimal** when the search tree is finite, all action costs are identical and all solutions have the same length. However limitating this may sound, there is an important class of problems that satisfies these conditions: the CSPs (*constraint satisfaction problems*). Maybe all the examples you thought about fall in this (rather common) category.

Answer (score -2):

Breadth-First Search (BFS) is optimal under certain conditions. The optimality of BFS refers to its ability to find the shortest path or the least-cost path from a start node to a target node in a graph. Here are the key conditions for BFS's optimality:

1. **Uniform Cost Edges**: BFS is optimal if all the edges in the graph have the same cost or no cost. Under this condition, BFS guarantees to find the shortest path in terms of the number of edges traversed. This is because BFS explores all nodes at the present depth level before moving on to the nodes at the next depth level.
2. **Unweighted Graphs**: BFS is particularly well-suited for unweighted graphs (where all edges have equal weight or no weight). In such graphs, the first time a node is visited is the shortest path to that node.
3. **Non-Decreasing Edge Path Cost**: BFS can also be optimal in graphs where the path cost is non-decreasing (i.e., each edge has a non-negative cost). This ensures that if there's a cheaper path to a node, BFS will find it before any more expensive paths.

However, in graphs with edges of varying costs, BFS is not guaranteed to be optimal. In such cases, algorithms like Dijkstra's algorithm or A* search, which take edge weights into account, are more suitable for finding the shortest or least-cost path.